# Lowercase and merge words together in JavaScript value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, javascript-objects

I can't seem to figure out what's going on on a form field input that gets stored inside a SharePoint column data collection.

I have a form field set when someone inputs a name that it automatically gets populated in a SharePoint list:

[image]

Here is what I currently have:

> Output: 
>   Profile Username: fhWestern Union

This is what I want to be able to achieve on all the inputs:

> Output: 
>   Profile Username: fhwesternunion

Here is the currently JavaScript code bit that I have grabbing the data:

```
ACI_Username: "fh" + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), // Username
```

I have tried adding this below and it did not work with my code.

> .toLowerCase().val()

Comment: replace spaces and you are using toLowerCase on the jQuery object

Comment: Call toLowerCase on the result of val, not the other way round.

Comment: Switch the order: `"fh" + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val().toLowerCase()`

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Is there a way that I can merge all the words together without adding a new line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$("#ACI_client-name-input").val()
```

With

```
$("#ACI_client-name-input").val().replace(/\s+/g,'').toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

this is it

```
ACI_Username = "fh" + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val().replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
```